# nohup not working in terminal (macos) (running python)

Tags: python, terminal, nohup

I recently tried running python programs in the background without having terminal or other application open, I tried using "nohup" in front of the terminal command which would run the python script (command used: nohup python3 -u "path would be here" > out &) but it still terminates the program whenever I close terminal. I just want to know if ther eis something i'm doing wrong or is there another method to run a python script without applications open in the background. Any help would be appreciated.

I attempted to use diffrent files and to remove parts such as the "> out" and looking online but didn't find anything.

Edit: the code I'm running is:

```
import time
x = 1
while 1 = 1:
   x = x + 1
   print(x)
   time.sleep(1)
```

(it works if I run it from terminal but don't close it)

Answer (score 0):

Another option to the `nohup [...] &` is to run the command/job as usual and disown it.

```
$ python3 -u "path would be here" > out &
$ disown
```

[This post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and) explains the differences between &, nohup and disown.

Another more complete answer than mine can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/134931).
They describe multiple ways to disassociate the process from the shell.
That includes `nohup`, `disown` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> Logout.

Comment: You are right @Friedrich, adjusted the comment to reflect that. Thanks for pointing this out.